# Get rid of divs in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have some issues while I'm working with media queries. When the width of the screen is less than 768px some content is supposed to disappear. It does. There's no content on a display, but if I have a look at the DOM, content still is there.

**How I've tried to get rid of this:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**How I think it would be:** JS code should parse current display resolution and if it reaches 768px of width, removes the content.

I'm not sure whether I'm thinking in the right-way or not. Could you explaind me(or even show a code) how to delete this content.

**Here's html template:**

```
<template>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left__row" v-if="ListSearch.length">
                    <LeftSideItem
                        v-for="item in ListSearch"
                        v-bind:item="item"
                        v-on:delete-item="deleteItem"
                    />
                </div>
              <div class="left__empty" v-else>
                <p >No search history</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: “*JS code should parse current display resolution and if it reaches 768px of width, removes the content.*” - why? Once the content is sent to the browser then it’s already there, why incur an additional performance penalty by using JavaScript to remove the elements that the user is (probably) unaware of? Also, if you remove the content based on screen width, if a desktop user resizes their window, you then end up having to reload content.

Comment: That has a point, but what if I use "preventDefault" in order to not reload a page?

Comment: looks like you are using `Vue`, if you insist to remove the content (even though I don't think you should), work with `v-if` and [`v-media-query`](https://github.com/AStaroverov/v-media-query)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Vue. I got what you are saying. But the situation is this - when the user is using not the mobile browser I'd like him to see the history of the search. It is the weather app and the search history column contains a summary of the cities he typed recently. When he brings it up with a mobile browser I'd like such information not to be shown because of tiny displays of cellphones. That's why I decided to remove it.

Comment: if you are going with `v-if` it will remove the element, while `v-show` hides it like what you did in your current css.

Comment: What you're describing is perfectly normal responsive behavior, where elements are hidden with CSS as appropriate. There's no need to reinvent the wheel. It does not matter that the element is still in the DOM. It's not visible to the user, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: As an iPad user I’ve been pondering your statement “JS code should parse current display resolution and if it reaches 768px of width, removes the content.” This would seem to mean that if I start off in portrait but twizzle round to landscape I won’t get the same data/layout as if I’d started off in landscape. Ouch.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {

        $('.left').remove();

    }
});
```

Comment: This is jQuery. There's no jQuery tag up there. Also, the DOM should not be directly modified with a Vue app.